# Episode From Old Sci-fi TV Series

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I'm trying to identify an episode of a 60's or 70's sci-fi TV series where a group of military people (and possibly scientists) in a very secluded base in possibly arctic or Antarctica are visited by a group of people and possibly a dog(?).

Each of these visitors are known by the people at the base but they were all known to be deceased. There was a wife, parents, etc. The visitors explain that there has been a discovery of some kind to bring people back to life, which they find hard to believe of course, but the people are there so even though skeptical they allow them into the base. They slowly start to realize that something's not quite right...

I can't remember much more detail or the ending - maybe aliens that took the appearance & personality based on the thoughts of the base guys?

I've searched for this show several times over the years with no luck. For some reason the show stuck with me and I'd love to see it again, even though I might be disappointed.

Comment: Can you check if this is an episode of *The Invaders (1967-1968)*? The aliens had human forms...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Distant Early Warning](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266471/) (an episode of the "The Wide World of Mystery" TV series)

IMDb:

> **Aliens infiltrate an Arctic research station**, and perform experiments
>   on the unsuspecting crew by mind control **which makes them think they
>   are seeing dead members of their families**.

Answer (score 1):

This is a movie, not a TV show, but...

[**The Thing** (1982)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-thing-1982)

> The Thing (also known as John Carpenter's The Thing) is a 1982 American science-fiction horror film directed by John Carpenter, written by Bill Lancaster, and starring Kurt Russell. The film's title refers to its primary antagonist: a parasitic extraterrestrial lifeform that assimilates other organisms and in turn imitates them. The Thing infiltrates an Antarctic research station, taking the appearance of the researchers that it absorbs, and paranoia develops within the group.

Comment: No, I'm familiar with The Thing, although I like the original better (The Thing From Another Planet) - but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like the plot of the 1982 SF-horror film *[The Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_%281982_film%29)*, directed by John Carpenter.

In in, an alien monster that is capable of imitating the victims it kills, wreaks havoc on an Antarctic research station.

It is based on the novella *Who Goes There?* by John W. Campbell jr, which has been adapted into a film a total of three or arguably four times (the 1972 film is a very loose adaptation).

Comment: Some similarities, but not what I'm looking for - thanks!